# What is formally the name of SML's type system?

Tags: types, computer-science, sml

Until now, I though SML was a convenient implementation of simply‑typed lambda‑calculus. Learning what's precisely simply‑typed lambda‑calculus is, I learned it cannot type‑check recursive functions.

I learned there exist a generalisation of simply‑typed lambda‑calculus, named System F. System F is polymorphic, has function returning type, which may make in some way think about SML's functors, but System F (according to something I have read), cannot type‑check infinite recursion, while this can be easily achieved with SML:

```
fun r x: int = (r x): int   (* Type‑checks *)
val y = r 0                 (* Infinite loop *)
```

So if SML's type system is neither simply‑typed neither System F, what is it (formally)? Or I am wrong and it's one of both?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717690/, it could be the next question that comes to you. It doesn't matter that it is for OCaml; the answers would be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's a [Hindley-Milner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) type system.

Comment: Seems a good match, at least confirmed by this source: [Lambda calculus](http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/funpro/ht09/handout/f10-lambda.html). It says “The type system used in SML is known as the Hindley Milner type system”. This one too: [Introduction](http://nax.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draft/design/intro.tex) [TeX]. It says: “Many typed functional programming languages including Haskell 98 and SML
are based on the Hindley-Milner type system […]”.

Comment: May be an extension though. This one: [Some advanced languages](http://matt.might.net/articles/best-programming-languages/), says: “Like Standard ML and OCaml, Haskell uses an **extension** of Hindley-Milner-style **type inference** […]”. It says an extension, it says type‑inference instead of type‑system. (still investigating based on your hint).

Comment: According to [Haskell/Polymorphism](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Polymorphism) Hindley Milner type system (and type inference), is a restriction of System F, and the former was favoured because type inference for full System F is undecidable (types can't be implicit and needs to be explicit, with System F).